# Pandas Count number of instances in a column and groupby from another column

Tags: pandas

I want to run a query on my Dataframe with pandas to count the number of times a 0 is in 'Days' column, not null in 'SUPPLY_CNT', AND groupby 'id' column.

```
Example Dataframe

   ID   |  Days | SUPPLY_CNT |
-----------------------------|
| 1561  |  -11  |     15     |
| 1561  |    0  |     05     |
| 1561  |   44  |     11     |
| 1561  |    0  |            |
| 1561  |    0  |     24     |
| 1561  |   56  |     24     |
| 1561  |    0  |     19     |
| 1561  |   92  |     21     |
| 2412  |  -789 |     09     |
| 2412  |  -456 |     09     |
| 2412  |  -321 |     31     |
| 2412  |    0  |            |
| 2412  |   99  |     32     |
| 2412  |    0  |     14     |
| 2412  |    0  |     18     |
| 7848  |   451 |     11     |
| 7848  |   3222|     21     |
| 7848  |    0  |     12     |
------------------------------

Expected Output:

1561     3
2412     2
7848     1
```

I have this query but need to groupby 'id'

```
(df.loc[(df['Days'] == 0) & (df['PAY_DAY_SUPPLY_CNT'].notnull())])
```

```
R Equivalent:

  filter(Days==0 & !is.na(PAY_DAY_SUPPLY_CNT))%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  count(Days)%>%
  arrange(desc(n))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create mask for test `0` values and not missing and convert to `integer`s:

```
m = ((df['Days'] == 0) & df['SUPPLY_CNT'].notna()).astype(int)
```

And for count aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = m.groupby(df['ID']).sum().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)

     ID  count
0  1561      3
1  2412      2
2  7848      1
```

For `Series`:

```
s = m.groupby(df['ID']).sum()
print (s)
ID
1561    3
2412    2
7848    1
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we first take rows in which the `Days` value is `0` AND `SUPPLY_CNT` is a number. Then we do groupby on that.

```
df.loc[(df['Days'] == 0) & ((df['SUPPLY_CNT'].notna()))].groupby('ID')['Days'].count()
```

**Output**

```
ID
1561    3
2412    2
7848    1
```

Comment: I think you get what I am after - thanks. It did return this error though: `Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

Comment: I changed it back to `.notnull()` and it worked. I see you tried another way but is there a reason `.notnull()` is not a good method to use?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you out.

```
df[df['Days']==0].groupby('ID')[['Days']].count().rename(columns = {"Days": "Count"})
```